# Сформировать одномерный массив, содержащий максимальные элементы каждого столбца матрицы

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста дорешать задачу.

> Дана квадратная матрица А, размером
> nxn. Сформировать одномерный массив,
> содержащий максимальные элементы
> каждого столбца матрицы.

Не могу сформировать массив, что я делаю не так?
Заранее большое спасибо :)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите кол-во строк");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите кол-во столбцов");
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] A = new int[n, m];
            Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив");

            for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(1); ++j)
                {

                    A[i, j] = r.Next(10, 100);
                    Console.Write(A[i, j] + "  ");

                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Максимальные элементы в каждом столбце");
            int k = m;
            int[] mas = new int[k];

                for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(1); ++i)
                {
                    int max = int.MinValue;
                    for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(0); ++j)
                    {
                        for (int c = 0; c < mas.Length; c++)
                        {
                            if (A[j, i] > max)
                            {
                                mas[c] = A[j, i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(mas[i]);
                }
                    Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] mas = new int[m];
for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(1); ++j)
    {
        A[i, j] = r.Next(10, 100);
        Console.Write(A[i, j] + "  ");
        if(i == 0){
            mas[j] = A[i,j];
        }else{
            if(A[i,j] > mas[j]){   
                mas[j] = A[i,j];
            }            
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```